# Enable button when form and subform inputs are valid

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following form I want to enable/disable button at the bottom of it only if form and subform are valid but right now it validates only with the forms inputs it doesn't seems to be using the subform (ng-form) inputs to validate:

This is a minimal version of what I need:

```
<!-- FORM BEGINNING -->
<form name="medsRefundForm" novalidate>
  <div class="card">

    <!-- NAME -->
    <label class="item fields" ng-click="isKeyboardOpenToTrue()">
      <input type="text"
             ng-model="userName"
             ng-blur="showFootBar()"
             name="username"
             ng-required="true"
             placeholder="Nombre del titular de la poliza">
    </label>
    <!-- ID NUMBER -->
    <label class="item fields" ng-click="isKeyboardOpenToTrue()">
      <input type="number"
             ng-model="idNumber"
             ng-blur="showFootBar()"
             ng-required="true"
             name="idnum"
             placeholder="Cédula / Nit">
    </label>
    <p>SUBFORM START</p>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          INNER SUBFORM
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->
    <ng-form name="subform">

      <!-- TITLE HOLDER NAME -->
      <label class="item fields">
        <input  type="text" placeholder="Nombre del titular de la poliza"
               ng-required="true"
               ng-click="showFootBar()">
      </label>
      <!-- TITLE HOLDER ID NUMBER -->
      <label class="item fields">
        <input  type="number" placeholder="Cédula / Nit"
               ng-required="true"
               ng-click="showFootBar()">
      </label>
    </ng-form>

    <div class="bottom-placeholder">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          I WANT TO ENABLE/DISABLE THIS BUTTON WHEN FORM IS VALID
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->
<div ng-hide="isKeyboardOpen">
  <button class="button button-block btn-policy"
          ng-disabled="!medsRefundForm.$valid"
          ng-click="continueForm()">ENABLE THIS WITH VALIDATION</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Now a link to sample:
http://play.ionic.io/app/8460480dc650

MY full HTML class is more complex link for i in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/veevkdAp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this your updated demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/0e46ee98e06b 
You can access validitity of child form with this `medsRefundForm.subform.$valid` and you need to put this in `ng-disabled` condition this way

```
ng-disabled="!medsRefundForm.$valid || !medsRefundForm.subform.$valid"
```

Plus you need to put `ng-model` for subform input elements. You were missing those. Angular validation does not work until you provide model to input elements. See following code of your's, you missed model

```
<input  type="text" placeholder="Nombre del titular de la poliza" ng-required="true" ng-click="showFootBar()">
```

See this [example](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/nestedforms/) for more understanding.

Comment: thank you very much this worked perfectly, is there anyway to add dinamically or at runtime `ng-required` for the subform as you can see in my full code this area will only be avaible based on a `toogleChecked` which is binded to `<ion-toggle>` over it, which has an `ng-model= "toogleCheked"` so I want the last two inputs to be required only if toggle was checked : toggleChecked = true

Comment: Well instead of assigning `ng-required` on run time, you can use toggle value to put a check at `ng-disabled` like this 
ng-disabled="!medsRefundForm.$valid || (!medsRefundForm.subform.$valid && toggleModel)"`

Comment: Had to include a subform for the first part: `        <ng-form name="firstSubform">` and then the other subform as: `        <ng-form name="secondSubform">` then at button to enable/disable added: `                ng-disabled="(!medsRefundForm.firstSubform.$valid && !toggleChecked) || (toggleChecked && !medsRefundForm.secondSubform.$valid)"`and it finally worked :D

Comment: yeah thanks for your help your really the life save in the ionic questions